# dynamically Convert SQL query to Mongo Shell scritp using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, mongo-shell

We are upgrading to MongoDB from SQL Server. All our writes are happening to SQL + Mongo and reads happen on MONGO.

As per our application architecture, we save some SQL queries stored in a table and execute them on need.

Since we now are doing all our reads from Mongo, I was wondering if there is way I can convert my SQL queries to Mongo at run-time

Example

```
select field1, field2 from mytable where ((TagId = 11232 OR TagId = 40923) AND (TagId = 4467 OR TagId = 3245))
```

Answer (score 0):

as this looks like nice feature request, there is no tool like that.